# ISTIO HTTPS-HTTP 404 NR route_not_found

Tags: http, https, istio, istio-operator

I am trying to configure TLS termination via Istio `HTTPS` -> `HTTP`.

`HTTP` 80 works fine.

`HTTPS` 443 works only for `/` path.

**HTTP 200:**

```
curl https://serviceA.example.com
```

**HTTP 404:**

```
curl https://serviceA.example.com/blabla
```

Istio access logs:

```
GET /blabla HTTP/2" 404 NR route_not_found
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: serviceA-gateway
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: HTTP
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "serviceA.example.com"
    - port:
        number: 443
        name: https
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        mode: SIMPLE
        credentialName: serviceA.example.com
      hosts:
        - "*"

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: serviceA-swearl
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:
    - serviceA.example.com
  gateways:
    - serviceA-gateway
  HTTP:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: serviceA.default.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 80
```

I am not sure what I did wrong. By looking at the docs everything should be working. Setup is ISTIO operator on AWS EKS with NLB.

Also, I have a certificate - secret in the istio-system namespace.
Service and Deployment have required labels.

***FIX: The issue was that I had on Ingress definition***

```
pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

It should be:

```
pathType: Prefix
```

[Configure Ingress pathType ImplementationSpecific behavior #26883](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/26883)

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer for better visibility.

As the OP mentioned in the question, problem is solved by setting

```
pathType: Prefix
```

in the ingress.

**Original message:**

> ***FIX: The issue was that I had on Ingress definition***

```
pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

It should be `pathType: Prefix`
https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/26883

You can find an explanation in this [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types):

> Each path in an Ingress is required to have a corresponding path type. Paths that do not include an explicit  `pathType`  will fail validation. There are three supported path types:
>
> - `ImplementationSpecific`: With this path type, matching is up to the IngressClass. Implementations can treat this as a separate  `pathType`  or treat it identically to  `Prefix`  or  `Exact`  path types.
> - `Exact`: Matches the URL path exactly and with case sensitivity.
> - `Prefix`: Matches based on a URL path prefix split by  `/`. Matching is case sensitive and done on a path element by element basis. A path element refers to the list of labels in the path split by the  `/`  separator. A request is a match for path  *p*  if every  *p*  is an element-wise prefix of  *p*  of the request path.